# webpack 2 cannot omit '-loader' error

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've been using webpack 1.x successfully on my React project up to this point. I'm now trying to migrate to webpack 2 and running into this problem:

In my actions.js files, I import JavaScript functions from other files -- see below:
[image]

When I run webpack, I get the following error. Looks like webpack is confusing my `import` statements with importing loaders -- see below:
[image]

Here's the webpack.config.js file that I've just converted to webpack 2 format:

```
var IS_DEV = false;
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require("path");

var _pluginsDev = [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
        moment: 'moment',
        ps: 'perfect-scrollbar'
    }),

];
var _pluginsProd = [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
        moment: 'moment',
        ps: 'perfect-scrollbar'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ // Minimizer, removing multiple occurances of imports et.c
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        compress: true,
        output: { comments: false }
    })
];

var _devtool = IS_DEV ? 'eval' : 'cheap-module-source-map';
var _plugins = IS_DEV ? _pluginsDev : _pluginsProd;
var _fileName = IS_DEV ? "./build/[name]-bundle.js" : "./dist/[name]-bundle.js";

var _bundles = {
    accounts: './UI/components/accounts/accounts.jsx'
};

module.exports = {
    entry: _bundles,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot"),
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: _fileName
    },
    devtool: _devtool,
    plugins: _plugins,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'stage-2', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
}
```

Any idea what's causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In new webpack versions, you can not omit `loader` prefix.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'fetch': 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
        moment: 'moment',
        ps: 'perfect-scrollbar'
    })
```

Comment: Thank you. You're right! Looks like I needed it for the `exports-loader` as well.